# Inequality of modulus of quadratic polymnomials in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, elementary-functions

I am trying to work out some stability conditions for ODE methods and during the computations one needs to solve the following inequality:

Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. For which $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $z=a+bi$ the following inequality holds

$$ |\alpha_2 z^2 + \alpha_1 z + 1| < | \beta_2 z^2 + \beta_1z + 1| .$$

I was able to reformulate the above into

$$ (\alpha_1^2 - \beta_1^2)(a^2+b^2) +  (\alpha_2^2 - \beta_2^2)(a^2+b^2)^2 + 2\left(
(\alpha_1 \alpha_2 - \beta_1 \beta_2)(a^2 +b^2)a + (\alpha_1 - \beta_1)a + (\alpha_2 - \beta_2)(a^2 -b^2)
\right)<0.$$

I would be grateful for a push in any direction - especially a more elegant one than the 'brute force' I used above.

Comment: The boundary is a quartic curve, as your computation shows. Without more context, there's probably nothing more to say. What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: I would love to get something like like "if $a<0$ and some additional equation holds then this is guaranteed." In particular, I don't necessarily look for the exact solution - necessary conditions on $\alpha_i ,\beta_i$ would be also great.

Comment: In fact those coefficients $\alpha_i ,\beta_i$ do have in my setting a particular shape - though \emph{very} complicated. Hence my first try was to move forward with a general inequality of quadratic polynomials. But it may be as you say - one cannot show much in general.